# Handling a conditionally defined newif, nested in an ifx conditional?

Tags: conditionals

Consider this MWE:

```
\documentclass[11pt]{book}

\def\entrytest{WORD}
\def\entrycurrent{NOWORD}
% \def\entrycurrent{WORD}

\ifx\entrytest\entrycurrent
  \newif\ifsomething
  \somethingfalse
\fi

\ifx\entrytest\entrycurrent
  \ifsomething\typeout{Yes}\else\typeout{No}\fi
\fi

\begin{document}
\end{document}
```

In the current case, I would have expected that `\ifsomething\typeout...` would have been "protected" by the `\ifx` that wraps it; but something is not right, because the code halts with:

```
...
No
! Extra \fi.
l.15 \fi

?
```

Of course, if `\def\entrycurrent{WORD}` so all of the `\ifx`s run in the "true" branch, then everything works as expected.

So how should I go about handling uses of `\newif`s which may have been themselves conditionally defined?

Comment: This `\ifx\entrytest\entrycurrent
  \newif\ifsomething` is a FFFFFFFFFAQ:-) Move the `\newif` before the `\ifx`.

Comment: http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/193205/strange-errors-while-writing-a-package/193211#193211

Comment: Many thanks, @DavidCarlisle - I think I found it, is it [TeX FAQ -- question label "conditional"](http://www.tex.ac.uk/cgi-bin/texfaq2html?label=conditional)? So in brief, I cannot have a `\newif` in a conditional; I can only set its values conditionally, right?

Comment: You can of course do anything but using such a command is so tricky that it is more or less never worth the effort compared to declaring it globally.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In the second `\ifx\entrytest\entrycurrent`, `\ifsomething` is undefined, so the *first* `\fi` matches `\ifx` and the second `\fi` is out of place.

It's not the macro name that makes something a conditional; only a token that is *defined* and is equivalent to one of the primitive conditionals counts.

What `\newif\ifsomething` does is

```
\let\ifsomething\iffalse
\def\somethingtrue{\let\ifsomething\iftrue}
\def\somethingfalse{\let\ifsomething\iffalse}
```

You probably want something like

```
\newif\ifsomething
\somethingtrue

\ifx\entrytest\entrycurrent
  \somethingfalse
\fi

\ifx\entrytest\entrycurrent
  \ifsomething\typeout{Yes}\else\typeout{No}\fi
\fi
```

but it's unclear why you would do this to begin with.

Comment: Many thanks, @egreg; I wasn't really clear about `\ifsomething` being undefined in that case; this post and @DavidCarlisle's comments clears things up! Will accept as soon as the 10-minute expires... Cheers!